# Plotting Graphs with gtk3 in C

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I'm looking for an alternative to gtkdatabox since it is using obsolete stuff. I have got a GUI, made with Glade (3.20), that shall display some data in a 2D-graph. It is all written in C so 'matplotlib' isn't the tool I am looking for, is it? When I tried to do this with gtkdatabox, I got this message while compiling:

```
error: unknown type name ‘GdkGC’
```

As [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch26s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.5) quotes, this type isn't available any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK+ 3 (as well as GTK+ 2 since 2.8) uses cairo for drawing. If those are simple graphs, you may draw them directly with cairo.

Here are code examples of a simple function drawn with GTK+ and cairo:

- https://github.com/liberforce/gtk-samples/tree/master/c/gtk2-graph
- https://github.com/liberforce/gtk-samples/tree/master/c/gtk3-graph

**EDIT:**

There's also some tries of simple plotting libraries out there on the web. One of them is slope:

- https://github.com/bytebrew/slope

Never used it, but at least it uses GTK+, cairo and last commit is 2 months old. Of course, like GtkDataBox, that's not a widget maintained by the GTK+ project, so you're still at the mercy of the maintainer willingness to maintain his software.